# Linux can't delete (rm) a file

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to delete a file with spaces in it but it's not working.

```
hw1:84$ ls
hw yoyo ~  misc.ml  test.ml
hw1:85$ rm hw yoyo ~
rm: cannot remove `hw': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `yoyo': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/home/linux/ieng6/cs130w/cs130wau': Is a directory
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to get used to use the **`Tab`** key and let the shell auto-complete your file names. It is smart enough to **escape** certain characters like spates.

Answer (score 8):

If the file is `hw yoyo ~` then you need to quote it otherwise the `rm` will try to remove three separate *(non-existent or even worse existent)* files:

```
rm "hw yoyo ~"
```

Spaces in filenames are generally not a good idea, having `~` combined with spaces is plain stupid! You will end up removing your home directory at some point.

As the files `hw` and `yoyo` don't exists in the current directory you get the error messages:

```
rm: cannot remove `hw': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `yoyo': No such file or directory
```

The file `~` also doesn't exist in the current directory but `~` is an alias for you home directory so you see the different error message for this:

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/linux/ieng6/cs130w/cs130wau': Is a directory
```

You are lucky `rm` doesn't remove directories without the `-r` option by default.

Answer (score 3):

When there are special characters such as space in the file name, the name must be put inside quote characters. Another way of dealing with this problem is escaping the special characters in the name.

So, using quote method you should do:

```
rm 'hw yoyo ~'
```

and using escape method you will do:

```
rm hw\ yoyo\ ~
```

Comment: **Warning** do **not** do `rm -rf /home/linux/ieng6/cs130w/cs130wau` @Reza the OP is not trying to delete his home directory, the shell interprets `~` as `/home/linux/ieng6/cs130w/cs130wau`. You have misinterpreted the shells error message and told the OP to delete his home directory! This is why you don't use spaces and special characters in filenames!

Comment: @sudo_O You are right. Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answers telling you to quote the file name or escape the special characters are correct.

In addition, though, if your shell supports it, you can use filename completion (as long as the file name doesn't *start* with a special character).  For example:

```
$ ls
hw yoyo ~
$ rm h<Tab>
```

Type `rm h`, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the shell will expand it to the longest unique prefix given the available file names. If that's the only file in the current directory whose name starts with `h`, it will expand to the entire name, *correctly escaped*. After hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I see:

```
rm hw\ yoyo\ ~
```

and I can just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to remove the file.

Or I can start by quoting the name:

```
$ rm 'h<Tab>
```

expands to:

```
$ rm 'hw yoyo ~'
```

It will even combine quoting and escaping where necessary:

```
$ touch 'foo$bar'
$ rm "f<Tab>
```

expands to:

```
$ rm "foo\$bar"
```

If your shell can remember the quoting rules for you, it can be faster and easier than remembering them yourself -- even if you already know them.

The above applies to bash. It's likely to work on other modern shells as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm "hw yoyo ~"

or 

rm hw\ yoyo\ ~
```

**in some special case, use single quote.**

e.g.

```
kent$  l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 0 Jan 18 23:54 a b $HOME

kent$  rm "a b $HOME"
rm: cannot remove ‘a b /home/kent’: No such file or directory

kent$  rm 'a b $HOME'

kent$  l
total 0
```